# What does this Apache Access Log mean?

Tags: php, apache, phpmailer

I have been trying PHPMailer in my localhost, but when I accessed the Apache Access Log, it says:

**::1 - - [28/Dec/2014:08:27:02 +0800] "GET /PHPMailer-master/testmailer.php HTTP/1.1" 200 62**

Does anyone know what this log means?

Comment: Can you be more specific? One could write a 25-page treatise on the information presented in this log entry and the technologies that it describes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably what's confusing you is the `::1` at the beginning. That is your localhost address in IPv6 (your computer's loopback adapter), which is often represented in shorthand as `::1`.  So in total, the log entry is saying:

1. A client at your local machine
2. at the noted timestamp
3. requested `/PHPMailer-master/testmailer.php`
4. via HTTP 1.1
5. returning a HTTP status of 200 OK
6. and the output sent back to the client was 62 bytes

From the [Wikipedia entry on IPv6 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address):

> The localhost (loopback) address, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, and the IPv6 unspecified address, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0, are reduced to ::1 and ::, respectively. This two-colon replacement may only be applied once in an address, because multiple occurrences would create an ambiguous representation.

Comment: Is this log the reason why my PHPMailer is not working?

Comment: @Jpineds No. The log entry expresses a nominal state for an HTTP request. If PHPMailer failed, something else went wrong and you may need to look in Apache's error log instead of the access log.

Comment: @Jpineds If you didn't receive a message sent by PHPMailer, there are many many many possible reasons for that, ranging from spam filters, to non-running SMTP services, to SPF records in DNS, to graylisting.

Answer (score 2):

It means that this PHP file of 62B has been requested and sent to client without error (code HTTP 200) with protocol HTTP/1.1. You also got the date and time.